# [Django-pymongo]: Retain Mongo connection across request?

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

I have below code to open connection to mongo cluster deployed in altas under django view.

```
def homePage(request):
    context = {}
    import pymongo
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(<connection str>)
    db = client.foo
    return render(request, 'Home/index.html', context)
```

I see for each request it opens a new connection which is adding delay to load page.
Is there any way i can move this connection code some where else and reuse connection handle across all request?

I tried moving code to settings.py and tried exporting db handle to views.py but after sometime connections times out.

```
Version of libs are:
Django                 4.0.1
django-settings-export 1.2.1
pip                    21.1.2
pymongo                4.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's your mistake in settings.py but the DB connection should be in settings.py
MongoDB connection Example in settings.py

```
#Create mongo client
mongo_client = MongoClient(
    host='localhost',
    post=1234,
    username='db_username',
    password='db_password'
)

#Access a database:
    db = mongo_client['DatabaseName']

#Access a specific collection
    my_collection = db.get_collection('CollectionName')
```